# Ajuste numeros decimais em uma lista de strings - Python

Tags: python, string, formatação, decimal

Espero que vcs possam me ajudar! Estou em um projeto onde estou criando alguns graficos para um sistema que eh usado por pessoas de varios paises. Por conta disso, criei uma funcao chamada *formatC* que, de acordo com a lingua do pais do usuario, a pontuacao (marcadores de milhar e decimal) eh alterada.

E agora, o meu problema eh o seguinte: ao plotar esses meus valores formatados no grafico, eu gostaria de padronizar o numero de casas decimais p todos, ou seja, se os valores estao arredondados com 2 casas decimais, todos devem conter duas casas decimais. Exemplo: 0.35, 0.20... E no python, o 0.20 eh representado como 0.2.

Vou colocar abaixo o exemplo que eu tenho para que vcs consigam rodar e testar!

```py
frequencies = [3, 1050, 2, 420, 60, 2]

freq = np.array(frequencies)

perc = freq/sum(freq)

perc2 = np.around(perc * 100, 2)

perc2

>array([ 0.2 , 68.31,  0.13, 27.33,  3.9 ,  0.13])


from babel.numbers import format_decimal
def formatC(values: list, culture_code: str = 'en-US'):

    """ Auxiliar function that returns a list of formatted numbers according to the given 
    culture code.
    
    :param culture_code: a str specifying the language used to set the decimal
    and big marks, defaults to 'en-US'
    :type culture_code: str
    :param values: a list of numbert to be formatted
    :type values: list
    """
    # Treating culture_code
    culture_code_treated = culture_code.replace('-', '_')
    # Creating empty list
    formatted_numbers = []
    # Appending the values formatted on the list created previously
    for i in range(len(values)):
        formatted_numbers.append(format_decimal(values[i], locale= culture_code_treated))
        
    # Returning the resulted list
    return(formatted_numbers)
```

```
test = formatC(perc2, 'en-US')
>['0.2', '68.31', '0.13', '27.33', '3.9', '0.13']
test2 = formatC(perc2, 'pt-BR')
>['0,2', '68,31', '0,13', '27,33', '3,9', '0,13']
```

E, a partir dessa ultima lista citada acima, eu quero que todos os numeros tenham 2 casas decimais, ou seja, o 0.2/0,2 eu quero que fique 0.20/0,20 (a msm coisa p 3.9/3,9)!

Alguem consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Oi Helena-  por favor, não faça mais isso - fiquei quase uma hora explicando uma resposta pra você e você _apagou_ a outra questão. Por sorte, pude copiar o texto que escrevi. 
Algumas pessoas aqui são chatas, e vão vir com "downvotes" e votos pra fechar, mesmo pra perguntas perfeitamente respondíveis. Vou colar minha resposta de volta.

Comment: Oi, mil desculpas! Eu sou nova aqui e nao sabia que outros usuarios podiam bloquear minhas perguntas. Apaguei pq pensei que ngm mais podia ve-la. Desculpa novamente e, ficou melhor a pergunta agora?

Comment: sim - está bom.

Há alguns usuários que tem o papel de moderadores (eu sou um usuário antigo, com bastante reputação, mas não tenho poder de moderação) - de vez em quando tento conversar com  os moderadores aqui por que acho que eles tem uma cultura  que não favorece novos usuários - ja vi perguntas que foram negativadas e bloqueadas aqui terem 4 votos positivos ao serem refeitas no stackoverflow em inglês.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade, você está fazendo certo já -

Só existe "número com duas casas depois da vírgula" ou na forma de string. Um "número" é um "número" - uma quantidade: "1", "1.0", "1.000" são o mesmo número. (e mesmo no caso de você usar a classe "int" para colocar o "1" e "1.0" num float, Python continua considerando os mesmos como iguais: não só a comparação " 1 == 1.0" é True, mas [1.0] usado como chave num dicionário funciona de forma intercambiável com 1. E esse comportamento é correto: número é número.

Então, até existe o tipo numérico "Decimal" em Python: ele pode te garantir que você vai ter números com 2 casas decimais na memória, e nunca vai ter um problema de arredondamento que vai gerar mais casas decimais. Agora, usando o tipo float, como você está fazendo - mesmo arredondando com o around ou o round nativo do Python, não dá pra garantir que os números vão se manter representáveis com duas casas decimais, sem valores mais quebrados - por que internamente eles são armazenados em base 2, e alguns números simplesmente viram "dizimas periódicas" quando você muda a base de representação.

Então, enquanto sua aplicação está rodando e processando os números- você usa números. Se tiver alguma necessidade específica por algoritmo de usar só duas casas decimais, use o tipo "Decimal", limitando o número de casas no context - senão, deixe os tipos float sem arredondar.

Nas interfaces do seu sistema com o mundo exterior: seja pra printar no terminal, pra gravar um arquivo no disco - seja um Excel, um arquivo texto, um CSV, ou gerar uma página HTML, com os números formatados para exibição - nesse ponto é que você aplica o "{:02f}".format(numero) - Não tem que se preocupar se na hora de fazer uma conta o número é "1." ou "1.00", "1.00000", por que são o mesmo número. Se não for uma conta numérica, mas precisar do número como string ) por exemplo, colocar ele como representação monetária - essa é a "borda" - e você usa o string.format nesse ponto.

Vi seu comentário agora - e percebi que você quer padronizar os números em um gráfico - então por favor, adicione o código que gera o gráfico - é com a matplotlib? -e aí vamos explorar como formatar os números para serem usados como labels no gráfico - a lógica acima permanece (provavelmente é é só passar a lista formatada como string na chamada a matplotlib, em vez dos números como números)

No exemplo que está depois de você editar a pergunta, retornar os números em strings formatadas com o numero de casas decimais é trivial - se for sempre o locale em Inglês - um pouco mais chato, se temos que levar em conta locales diversos.

Não sei de onde em o format_decimal que você usa no seu código (a ideia era a gente poder executar aqui, mas sem os "import"s, isso não é possível). Podemos usar a função "format_string" da biblioteca "locale" padrão do Python -

E além disso, vamos usar também uma sintaxe do Python chamada "list comprehension" que reduz um trecho de três linhas e várias chamadas de função para apenas uma.

Então, onde você tem:

```
   formatted_numbers = []
    # Appending the values formatted on the list created previously
    for i in range(len(values)):
        formatted_numbers.append(format_decimal(values[i], locale= culture_code_treated))
```

Com list comprhensions fica:

```
formatted_numbers = [format_decimal(value, locale=culture_code_treated) for value in values]
```

(Aqui, se usa o "for" inline - ele executa, e executa a expressão antes dele uma vez para cada elemento na sequencia dada para o for (a variável values. À parte de usar essa sintaxe, em Python nunca precisamos fazer for  i in range(len(sequencia)): valor = sequencia[i] ... - ofor em ython sempre percorre sequências - você não precisa contar o índice, pra primeira coisa dentro do for ser pegar o elemento naquele índice.

Bom - mas esse aí é o mesmo código que você tinha - não sei ainda quanl é a função "format_decimal" - e pode ser que ela não aceite a expressão para formatação numérica, que precisamos - então vamos usar locale.format_string - que aceita uma string de formato na sintaxe usando "%" - a primeira forma de interpolação de strings do Python, que herda do prinf da linguagem C. Antes de se chamar o locale.format_string tem que se configurar o locale, com a função set_locale:

```py
import locale

def formatC(values, culture_code="en-US"):
   ...
   previous_locale = locale.get_locale(locale.LC_NUMERIC)
   locale.set_locale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, culture_code.replace("-", "_"))
   formatted = [locale.format_string("%.02f", value) for value in values]
   locale.set_locale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, previous_locale)
   return formatted
```

Na pergunta original, você tinha acrescentado que a função `format_decimal` que você está usando, vem da biblioteca `babel`. Consultei a documentação da biblioteca (na verdade, direto o código fonte, que no ambiente do ipython pode ser visto apenas se colocando a função seguida de `??`) - e, não, eles não aceitam uma forma auxiliar -só convertem os números sem arredondamento.  Mas a função da biblioteca padrão `locale` do Python, como usei acima, aceita - passo a string `"%.02f"` para ela.

Comment: Entao, @jsbueno... eu nao consigo te passar um exemplo dos graficos pq eles fazem parte de uma estrutura de classes enorme e interna da empresa...Mas o que eu preciso na essencial esta na minha pergunta mesmo. Estou procurando um jeito de pegar o resultado do uso da formatC (lista de strings) e, quando o numero tiver uma casa decimal so, acrescentar o zero. Nao sei se fui clara, ou se nao entendi a sua explicacao

Comment: sim - isso está respondido no final.  A minha versão da FormatC retorna a lista como você disse que precisa na pergunta, e respeita o código de locale (isso que voce chamou de "culture_code" - a babel também usa os locales internamente - são padrões internacionais que vem configurados no sistema operacional, não é nem no Python)